# TypeScript overloaded generic function's return type inferred incorrectly when used with Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the following code, the only difference between `getDocsWithIdThatWorks` and `getDocsWithIdThatComplains` is the callback they are passing to `Array.prototype.map`. In one case it's a function expression, and in the other it's an overloaded, generic function. In the first case, TypeScript perfectly understands and agrees about the return type of the overloaded function. But when passing the overloaded function's reference  directly as an argument to `Array.prototype.map`, TypeScript suddenly infers the return type as `DocumentWithId<unknown>`, despite the fact that the array being mapped is clearly typed as `QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>`. Why is that so?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsEFcC2FwDKIcADgM4AW6YAPACoB8yA3gFACQwAJgFzJlgooAOYcucMHAAUASj51kAH2RYQXCDFAQurAL6tWoSLEQoAilmgBPDNjyFi5KrUbIIAD0hqyaTLnxgRKSU1PRMbOzikrLyegZG0PBIvnYBAOrAYBQAklxhLKzIyNx8AkIgokVRcAD8sfqG4ImmyBbWtv7gGVm5%20WxFJfyCIoXI1fUGrDCqCGDA6CDIAO6ZOXmMUlx%209mB8bVA22wFBTqGMcq2WBx073WthUzNzC8urvRtbqeB8N8eOIS4GBdfl03usGI8QLN5osVj1wZsjt8Up1Av9nPllPtDl80cEMecfkiwHd3kwsVccajSeCCkUoBAwFgoIt%20kVirwxsSAHTcAA0oyqEjgfE%20qO51VkAqK%20gaYCsJHMlPyAF5kLJkCqmAAFKDoHDAMgQGjYkF406AgDaAF0Iaw4GQrFDkNMoc9FsJGbYyDS6BQJGl0FAANZkMJSACOlL2ysJyF1%20sNxtNxJpYRt4VGCAWAmQDLIWAANmBNcg4Es4JlkFHrLJRgymSy8xAC8XuThSFJNjJNUw4WtuzI4vbHc7XdCXp6wN7ff6wABhfUkQuVkBhjY1g4x6xhC4Jg1Gk2Us1pxgZunIbNrkv5osltXlyslzdWOv0xnMxa3tsdkhSfu5EO%20hAA)

```js
interface DocumentSnapshot<T> {
    id: string
    data(): T | undefined
}

interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends DocumentSnapshot<T> {
    data(): T
}

interface DocumentWithId<T> {
  id: string
  data?: T
}

interface QueryDocumentWithId<T> {
  id: string
  data: T
}


function withId<T>(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>): QueryDocumentWithId<T>
function withId<T>(document: DocumentSnapshot<T>): DocumentWithId<T>
function withId<T>(document: DocumentSnapshot<T> | QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>): DocumentWithId<T> | QueryDocumentWithId<T> {
  return {
    id: document.id,
    data: document.data(),
  }
}

type Query<T> = () => Promise<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>[]>

async function getDocsWithIdThatWorks<T>(query: Query<T>): Promise<QueryDocumentWithId<T>[]> {
  const result = await query()
  return result.map((d) => withId(d))
}

async function getDocsWithIdThatComplains<T>(query: Query<T>): Promise<QueryDocumentWithId<T>[]> {
  const result = await query()
  return result.map(withId)
}
```

Comment: @Dai that's correct! it also works if I pass the generic type to `map` manually. I'm trying to find out why I have to do any of these things at all.

Comment: TypeScript only properly resolves overload call signatures when you *call* it.  So `d => withId(d)` allows the compiler to resolve it to the first call signature because `d` is of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>`. But just passing `withId` doesn't do that; the compiler essentially just "gives up" and picks the last call signature (assumed to be the most general).  I could write that up as an answer if it fully addresses your question; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I'd love a write up that includes referfences to the TS docs or spec please!

Comment: @ziad-saab Hint: consider how structural-typing and type-equivalence works in tsc, then   make `QueryDocumentWithId.data` optional and you'll get a different error message which should get you 90% there. HTH (i.e. TypeScript thinks that `document.data()` _always_ returns `T | undefined`, so the returned new object's `data:` property is also typed as `T | undefined` which always satisfies `DocumentWithId<T>` but _never_ `QueryDocumentWithId<T>` - but because the return-type is a union that's perfectly fine and compiles. Basically, your types are too similar and TS can't tell them apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#35501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35501).  TypeScript can only properly resolve call signatures for [overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) when such functions are actually *called*.

When you write `d => withId(d)`, you are actually calling `withId` with a parameter of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>`, and the compiler selects the first call signature, as desired.

But when you just pass `withId` to `map()`, you are not calling `withId` and so the proper overload resolution does not happen.  Instead the compiler just "gives up" and picks the last signature.  And that results in the error you're seeing.

This happens whenever the compiler has to infer a type involving an overloaded function that it does not call.  I don't see direct documentation about this for *generic* type inference, but it is mentioned in the [documentation about *conditional* type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), where it says:

> When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the *last* signature (which, presumably, is the most permissive catch-all case). It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types.

Comment: I'm fine with this being the compiler's behaviour, but the fact there's no compiler warning or other message explaining that overload-resolution doesn't happen when passing a func is what's frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the GitHub issue. The documentation you linked to is also insightful.